# Runtime error not showing in updated android studio logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I am using windows 8.1 and i have installed updated android studio .But when my application is getting crash while debugging its not showing error log for what reason its crash.

Comment: you can see it by pressing `Alt+6`

Comment: i am getting logcat and whatever log message i have printed i am getting but , not able to find error!

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the Logcat by pressing **Alt+6** in Windows and **CMD+6** in Mac.